# Dockerfile FROM vs Docker-compose IMAGE

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I am currently in the process of learning Docker. After reading the docs and a few articles I obviously have more questions than answers. Most intriguing one for me at the moment is: what is the difference between

```
FROM some:docker-image
```

In Dockerfile and

```
image: digitalocean.com/php
```

In docker-compose.yml

I do understand that they should grab the image and create a container from it. What I don't understand is what happens if we will specify both at the same time, for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
```

Both docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile have images specified in them.
What happens when those images are different?
Will docker-compose.yml always win and for that one service? Will it use only this 'top' image?
Will they overlap somehow?
Or maybe I got it all wrong?

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786256/docker-compose-specifying-image-vs-dockerfile) but I am still not sure if I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is **build** vs. **run**

Think of images as apps and containers as a process running an app.  Running an app does not change the app.  Running a container likewise does not change the image.  Images are built from `Dockerfiles` using `docker build` and are persistent. Containers are created as needed by `docker run`, `docker-compose`, kubernetes, or similar tools from images and are intended to be temporary.

The `Dockerfile` is used by the `docker build` command to build a new image. 
 In the `Dockerfile` the first line usually specifies the base image with `FROM`, i.e. `FROM nginx`.  Subsequent `RUN` lines in the `Dockerfile` provide the additional steps that `docker build` will execute in a shell, within the context of the `FROM` image, to create the new image.  Note that the `Dockerfile` does not specify the name of the new image. Instead, the new image is named in the `-t some/name` option to `docker build`

The `docker-compose.yml` file specifies a group of images to download and run together as part of a combined service.  For example, the `docker-compose.yml` for a  blog could consist of a web server image, an application image, and a database image and would specify not only the images but also possibly how they communicate.

Since docker builds and docker compose are separate operations, there is no conflict or detection of differences.  The `docker-compose.yml` controls what is going to be download and run, and you can also build whatever you like.

Also, as @David Maze mentioned in comments:

> If you use both options then Docker Compose will build the image as specified and then tag it using the image: name; this can be confusing if you're putting a "standard" image name there.

My guess is if you do that, you might end up with an image, say `nginx` on your own machine that does not match the Dockerhub image. Don't do that.  Instead, use unique names for any images that you build.

Comment: If you [use both options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) then Docker Compose will build the image as specified and then tag it using the `image:` name; this can be confusing if you're putting a "standard" image name there.

Comment: Guys, both answers are great thanks. I do remember that part of docs however after I saw different configs it was a bit confusing. So if I use both then the image from compose will just give a name to the image. If only specify image in compose for example nginx and don't use any docker Dockerfike it will grab nginx image anyway, this will then be replacement of FROM ?

Comment: @Robert  It is not a replacement for `FROM` because there is no image building step in docker compose when there is no Dockerfile.  docker compose will create some containers. Images are not containers.  Containers are created from images.  Think of Images as apps and Containers as a process running an app.  Does this help?

Comment: Once the concepts are understood, I highly recommend you confirm anything you read through experimentation and testing.

Comment: @Paul I guess it's just my poor choice of words. What I meant was: when in compose file image is specified(e.g nginx) and there is no Dockerfile specified for that service compose will try to grab that ready image from remote repository. When dockerfile and image are specified in docker compose, Dockerfile will be used to build image and image tag from docker composer will give it a name. However like you said I will test that thoroughly. The reason I am asking so many questions is I don't want to randomly assume that this is always what's gonna happen I rather understand the process.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly, what you're all saying that a `docker-compose.yml` file with the tag `image: httpd:alpine` will build an Apache web-server container.  But a similar `docker-compose.yml` file with the same `image:` tag but also referencing a `Dockerfile` which starts `FROM nginx:alpine`, will create a container that runs Nginx web server (though that container will be labelled as an Apache server). Did I understand correctly? @Paul @Robert

Comment: @cartbeforehorse I think you did understand that correctly. I just looked at the quote in this answer and it says that if you have a `docker-compose` with an `image` option and with `Dockerfile` then the Docker should use Dockerfile to build an image. Then that that name from `image` should be used to tag(name) it. You can also set up some quick example to see if that is going to happen (use Alpine versions as they are small and take less time to set up)

Comment: @Robert : I see where the confusion comes from and why you posted the original question. The `image:` tag in the YML file is misleading in that it's actually the `Dockerfile` that builds the image (it is docker-compose which executes the container which runs on that image). In my test, `Dockerfile` builds `FROM nginx:alpine`, but `docker ps -a` displays an image-name of `Apache` because that's what the `image:` tag in the YML file says. Contrary to what people say, the `image:` tag and `Dockerfile FROM` clause do (can) conflict, and cannot be considered functionally mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens if we will specify both (image and Dockerfile) at the same time:

If the image does not exist, docker-compose attempts to pull it, unless you have also specified build, in which case it builds it using the specified options and tags it with the specified tag.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).