# How can the image name in this docker compose file be found?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I wrote a `docker-compose.yml` file referencing this tutorial: [Running PostGraphile in Docker](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/running-postgraphile-in-docker/#update-docker-compose-file), but when I run this command `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d` to update an image an error occurred:

```
WARNING: Some service image(s) must be built from source by running:
    docker compose build graphql
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for forum-example-graphql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

But if I run `docker-compose up -d`, everything is OK.

I wonder how the `forum-example-graphql` image in the following snippet can be found(from docker hub?)?

```
graphql:
    container_name: forum-example-graphql
    restart: always
    image: forum-example-graphql
    build:
        context: ./graphql
    env_file:
        - ./.env
    depends_on:
        - db
    networks:
        - network
    ports:
        - 5433:5433
    command: ["--connection", "${DATABASE_URL}", "--port", "5433", "--schema", "public", "--append-plugins", "postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter"]
```

I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56998475/3552975) that the image name in the compose file is based on the created image name, but I did not name the local image as `forum-example-graphql`.

In another service the configuration is as follows:

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    networks:
        - network
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

The image value is set as `postgres:latest` and the image is pulled directly from docker hub using this config, given no context and Dockerfile.

Then I wonder how the local image is named and how does it relate to the service image value.

Comment: (Consider deleting the `image:` line to avoid this warning, and let Compose pick the image name itself.  You similarly do not need `container_name:` and can probably delete every `networks:` block in the whole file.)

Comment: @DavidMaze So if I set `image:` the pulled image `node:alpine` from docker hub will be locally named `forum-example-graphql`?

Comment: You need to `docker-compose build` this image (which could be `FROM node:alpine` or anything else).  If you don't set `image:` then Compose will pick a name for it.  If you do set it, then typically you'd want to set it to an actual Docker Hub or other registry name `image: registry-example-com/forum/graphql` where you could `push` or `pull` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose pull, pulls the image `forum-example-graphql` from the image registry, default (docker hub).

but since it is specified to be built from the directory

```
build:
    context: ./graphql
```

Hence, that image need not be pulled, you can use this option `--ignore-buildable` with `docker-compose pull` to skip images with local build context.

Also `docker-compose up -d` by default pulls image if not available and smartly ignores local contexts and pulls images which are to be pulled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I am not wrong, you mean that 1) docker-compose checks the Dockerfile in `build: context`, and if an image is set, the image will be pulled from an image registry and the local image will be named after what we set in `docker-compose.yml > services > graphql > image`, otherwise 2) the `image:` config will be used to pull an image from a registry and the name of the local image will be the default name. Am i right?

Comment: yes, docker-compose pull checks for the image in registry. and docker-compose up -d does both. 1) checking the file in registry, 2) building the image on local if build: context is provided

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do a `docker-compose pull` command on the `forum-example-graphql`-docker, because it does not exist in the publically accessible Docker Hub repository. Part of the tutorial is that you create that image yourself by using `docker-compose build` (see [here](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/running-postgraphile-in-docker/#build-images)).

After performing the `build` command, you can use the `up -d` to start the image that you build (named `forum-example-graphql`).